# making httpwebrequest using proxy fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make httpwebrequests using a list of proxy ips, but each time I make a request I get an error message : Unable to connect to the remote server.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
Dim request as HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
Dim oldProxy as IWebProxy = CType(request.Proxy, IWebProxy)
Dim proxy as New WebProxy()
Dim newuri as new Uri("http://" & proxyIP)

proxy.Address = newuri
request.Proxy = proxy
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

Try
   request.Timeout=18000
   request.UserAgent = useragent
   request.KeepAlive = False
   **webreponse = tryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)**
   request.accept="*/*"
   ...
```

It fails on the request.getresponse line above. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out changed the code...

```
Dim request as HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
Dim proxy as New WebProxy()
Dim newuri as new Uri("http://" & proxyIP)

request.Proxy = proxy

Try
  request.Method="GET"
  request.Timeout=18000
  request.UserAgent = useragent
  request.KeepAlive = False
  **webreponse = tryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)**
  request.accept="*/*"
```